# 4 channel matrix coded as an image and then in a string

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a byte sequence, that consists of image data . The image data is a 4 channel matrix. The byte sequence looks like this --

```
b'33333\xf3#@33333\xf3#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xd9#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@fffff\xa6#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\xcd\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8c#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@33333s#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99Y#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@fffff&#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\xcd\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x0c#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@33333\xf3"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xd9"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@fffff\xa6"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\xcd\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\x8c"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@33333s"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x7f33333\xf3#@\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99Y
```

Ofcourse its not complete, because its a string with 400X400 with 4 channel and each channel is 4 bytes float.

I can see the byte sequence, but how do I reconvert it into an image file using python?

Comment: I do not believe those are 4-byte singles.  I believe they are 8-byte doubles.  The first three elements are 9.975, 9.975, nan, nan.  That pattern repeats.

Comment: time to tap the "focus" sign. please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417486#417486. you've got several things to address individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
import array
data = array.array('d')
data.fromstring(yourdata)
```

When I run this on your string, I get:

```
array('d', [9.975, 9.975, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.924999999999999, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.875, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.825, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.775, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.725, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.674999999999999, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.625, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.575, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.525, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.475, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.424999999999999, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.375, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.325, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.275, nan, nan, 9.975, 9.225, nan, nan, 9.975])
```

You then have the job of converting this to an [x,x,4] array.  Numpy can help with that.

### Followup

The first eight bytes are '33333\xf3#@'.  In hex, that's `33 33 33 33 33 f3 23 40`.  Converting to little endian, that's `0x4023f33333333333`.  That happens to be the binary representation of the floating point number 9.975.

Comment: that's the binary equivalent of a "repeating decimal". 9.975 has no finite representation in binary, like 1/3 has no finite representation in decimal (0.333...).

Comment: The string you posted is truncated, so only the first 526 characters are there.  To see that line use `x[:520]`, which is a multiple of 8.  If you really have a 400x400 4 channel image, you will have a string 5 megabytes long.

Comment: @TimRoberts There is another issue. The string above is really a type string. So, the x[:520]doesnt work. Is there a way to encode the string into type bytes?

Comment: which means - the data is actually -> str type and data = 'b\'33333\\xf3#@33333\\xf3#@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xf8\\x7f\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xf8\\x7f'. As you see, \ are escaped..

Comment: That's hard for me to believe.  How would you have acquired a string like that?  I suspect you are confusing what the variable contains with how it is presented.  If you really have a Unicode string that contains a byte string (?????), you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert it to a byte string.

Comment: well, the data comes from a csv file, and when you read the csv file it always give you a string

Comment: You have 5 megabyte entries in a CSV file?  I have some concerns about your data management processes..... ;)